# How to parse transaction payload in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode

I am trying to use a chaincode with minifabric. The transaction payloads are shown correct when the payload is a number but when I send string as payload the payload returned is encoded like this "\262\027\236\267W\332\226\307\254\205\347\255\331\366\245\261" .
How do I get the string as payload.

Comment: You need to provide more detail here such as a chaincode code of the transaction you are running, the client code you are using to invoke that transaction

Comment: are you invoking the chaincode function from command line or something like javascript gateway?

Answer (score 0):

to get actual value of string try to convert it to string by using `toString()`  function with the response